# Visual Studio ClickOnce Publish fails

Tags: c#, clickonce

I have created a C# 4.0 WinForms application using Visual Studio 2010 Premium SP1 on Windows 10.

Over the months I have modified and deployed this same App many times, using ClickOnce.

I have never had any difficulty until today.

I made one small modification to the code, which works successfully.

However, after building, and attempting to publish, 2-separate errors are thrown, as listed below.

```
#1) Cannot publish because a project failed to build.
#2) An error occurred while signing: The parameter is incorrect.
```

My application does contain a separate project, which is only a Splash Screen project.

If I go to Solution Explorer and attempt to build the 2nd project, it builds fine.

I have also tried to Build > Publish by using the menu in Solution Explorer, rather than from the Publish pane of VS.

Not only is it puzzling why a publish is failing suddenly now, but the error messages do not provide any clue as to where in the code a problem is arising, if indeed it's in the code.

Can anyone suggest how to correct this situation, as I am unable to publish my app any longer.

Comment: "An error occurred while signing: The parameter is incorrect."  It's unable to sign the ClickOnce manifest.  This is the clue in your error messages.

Comment: Did your certificate expire?

Comment: I do not know what parameter is being referred to as incorrect. I'm not passing any parameter @Amy. Also, No, my certificate has not expired@Crowcoder.

Comment: @CodeMann That is a clue that you need to investigate.  The signing process is failing.  Find out why.  We can't tell you; that information isn't in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This error was puzzling, as I've used ClickOnce to deploy modified versions of my App many times. On a hunch, I decided to change the TimeStamp server from the following:

> http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll

to this:

> http://timestamp.globalsign.com/?signature=sha2

Since researching this error referenced the fact that Microsoft would no longer recognize SHA1, but needed the SHA2 cryptography, I tried using this latter server and after compiling, it allowed my app to do a successful publish.
If anyone else runs into this problem, the above solution may prove useful.